# Seemingly difficult probabilistic method question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Hello I was asked the following question and I really am not sure how to show such results.

I believe it could maybe be done using the probabilistic method.

Consider a graph on $ m$ vertices, for any pair of vertices , we include an edge between $i$ and $j$ with probability $1/2$. This is done independently and for every pair $i,j$.

The question is to show that for any two vertices, with large probability they share at least $\frac{m}{4}-\sqrt{m\log m}$ common neighbours.

My thoughts:

It seems like it may be possible to use Chernoff bounds, for any given vertex, if we let $X_{i}$ denote the random variable of the number of neighbours of some vertex $i$, I believe $$E[X_{i}]=\frac{m-1}{2}=\mu$$

So that could possibly be used in computing a probability using Chernoff bound.

However, I don't see how I can incorporate that we are looking for shared common neighbours. Maybe using pigeonhole principle?

Maybe it is related to Ramsey theorem and edge colouring?

Or maybe their is a whole different approach that would work a lot more efficiently?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: For a vertex $v$, the probability that it is adjacent to both $x$ and $y$ is 1/4. So the number of such vertices is a sum of ind r.v.s and the Chernoff bound works.

Comment: @Aravind  Thanks. But in terms of what your random variable is here, are you saying we should sum over all possible pairs?

Comment: where the total random variable has expectation n/4 ?